# Kotlin Coroutine How to cancel async await()

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, deferred

I have been trying to apply coroutine to my android app but found some strange thing about async coroutine. Base on this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629)

```
val deferred = async { … }
deferred.cancel()
val result = deferred.await() // throws JobCancellationException!
```

If you cancel the deferred before await code is called, it will throw exception. It seems like it just doesn't allow you to cancel an async coroutine. How do I cancel the deferred without throwing an exception?

Or the only way is just to add try-catch around every await? But that seems verbose to me. Is there any cleaner approach to it?

Comment: There is an exact answer in this article: [Cancellation in coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629), section "Job.join vs Deferred.await cancellation". The code (and behaviour) described there are exactly as yours.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If you want to wait for a cancelled coroutine to complete you should join, as explained in the article. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: @madhead, I came from that article. I have edited the question a bit. Sorry I hope it makes more sense this time.

Comment: @alediaferia sorry about the confusing question, hope now it makes more sense.

Comment: So, have you seen this: "Here’s why we get the exception: the role of `await` is to suspend the coroutine until the result is computed; since the coroutine is cancelled, the result cannot be computed. Therefore, calling await after cancel leads to JobCancellationException". What's unclear to you?

Comment: @madhead I have read those parts and the question is, what if I still want to cancel it but not crashing the app? Is it the standard practice to just surround it with try-catch so it handles the exception?

Comment: There are no other known ways to suppress the exception, so, yes, you should use try / catch. But most probably you're doing something wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps your coroutine design is wrong, maybe it's better to just cancel parent job (or scope) - that will prevent `await` from being executed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `await()` after `cancel()` leads to `CancellationException`. From the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) of `await()` method:

> This suspending function is cancellable. If the **Job** of the current
>   coroutine is cancelled or completed while this suspending function is
>   waiting, this function immediately resumes with `CancellationException`.

`CancellationException` is thrown "silently" **without crashing an app**, we can read that from the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/):

> If exception is `CancellationException` then it is ignored (because that
>   is the supposed mechanism to cancel the running coroutine)

If you want somehow handle the exception, cleanup resources or want your code continue execution after calling `await()` use `try-catch` block as usual:

```
val deferred = async { ... }
deferred.cancel()
try {
    val result = deferred.await()
} catch (e: CancellationException) {
    // handle CancellationException if need
} finally {
    // make some cleanup if need
}

// ... other code which will be executed if `await()` throws `CancellationException`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a CoroutineScope after one of its jobs is cancelled, use a SupervisorJob for it. The SupervisorJob is not cancelled when its childs get cancelled.

```
val reuseableScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
```